# Excel won't let me paste

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

This is my first time posting here.
Here's my problem. I entered a custom function to count the coloured cells.

```
Function COUNTIFCOLOUR(Colour As Range, rng As Range) As Long
Application.Volatile

Dim NoCells As Long
Dim CellColour As Long
Dim rngCell As Range
CellColour = Colour.Interior.Color
For Each rngCell In rng
    If rngCell.Interior.Color = CellColour Then
        NoCells = NoCells + 1
    End If
Next
COUNTIFCOLOUR = NoCells
End Function
```

So far so good. To calculate automatically upon making changes, I used this code.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
ActiveSheet.Calculate
End Sub
```

The problem is, after using the ActiveSheet.Calculate code, Excel doesn't let me paste things I copy, although I can do it through the clipboard. If I delete the ActiveSheet.Calculate code, everything returns to normal, meaning that I can Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V (or copy, paste using the mouse.

Can anybody help me with this? Bear in mind that I don't know how to write code. I found everything pre-made online. I'm using Microsoft Office 2019.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem!

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
  Application.EnableEvents = False
  ActiveSheet.Calculate
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

If your spreadsheet is slow with lots of calculations that are being done unnecessarily, try instead:

```
ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Calculate
```

Comment: The second one worked. Thank you. It calculates automatically the function and resolved the paste issue